# Google action not working in iphone's Google assistant application

Tags: iphone, actions-on-google

I am developing Google Action. I am able to test with google assistant in android mobile successfully. But when I use my action in Iphone google assistant i am not able to access my google action. it says "to let me read out that information, turn on personal results in the google Home app". But I don't have Google home app. in android it is working without google home app. Is there any steps or settings need to change to make it work?

Comment: You can try installing the Google Home app on iPhone. This may be the reason because android apps and google are not happily welcome on iOS platform.

Comment: Now I installed all the google apps including Google Home also. But  it says same message  again.

Comment: One month before Google Assistant was worked without any issue. latest update makes some setting changes that affect the action invoke.

Comment: That's tricky, Yeah updated might cause the reason, now I guess you need to look at the change log what has been updated, I am suspecting there could be a security privacy related updates can cause such behaviour.

Comment: i tried all privacy and security related changes in google Home app , Google assistant and  iphone privay. But no luck.

Comment: If you are testing on iOS, you will need to download the Google Assistant iOS app, and be logged into the same Google account you are developing your Action with to invoke the test version of your Action.

Comment: I have google assistant app latest version  19.28702 in my iphone x and logged in the same google account i am using for devlopment. last month i was able to test without any issue.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue on iOS google assistant. I'm facing this issue when I say "Talk to Mercedes". Maybe it is not just related to your action that you're developing?

Comment: it looks like google home app for ios does not have default device in assistant devices settings . it needs at least one device needs to connect. But in google assistant it has one default device in assistant device settings as our own iphone. this is the reason why we can not use google home directly without connect any device.